# Media Server for Video chat

Tags: video-streaming, media, red5

I am using red5 as media server for video chatting , but it consumes lots of resources , i have 768 MB of brust ram and 512 MB dedicated RAM, but still facing error: can not allocate memory. I am looking for any alternative solution that can work with my current resources,

is there any media server in your knowledge please share. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly this is probably something you have to overcome on the hardware side. Red5 is Java based which automatically means it's a bit of a resource hog because of it's architecture however, the mere fact that you are taking video frames, probably transcoding, then serving the feed video/audio will always mean that you will need a fair amount of immediate memory for the server to work with. I'd much sooner upscale the RAM (512 really isn't much at all) than change an effective solution. FMS will easily consume the same and cost you more for the license than the extra RAM will cost you.

You can get cloud servers with 3gb ram for $10 a month these days